# remove actions defined with function(){...} wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

Have you got an idea how to remove *actions* or *filters* in **Wordpress** (from a plugin in my case) when those are defined like so:

add_action('action_tag', function(){...});
or
add_filter('filter_tag', function(){...});

They are defined inside the function *add_action* or *add_filter* so I have no clue witch 'function_name' I should use to remove it.

remove_action($tag, ***what am I supposed to put in here?***, $priority);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). To remove anonymous functions from filters or actions, you have to use the same function body and priority you used when they were added like so:

```
// Add it.
add_filter( 'tag', function ( $param ) {
    return $param;
}, 10, 1 );

// Remove it.
remove_filter( 'tag', function ( $param ) {
    return $param;
}, 10 );
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.. This will delete all hooks that are anonymous functions

```
global $wp_filter;
foreach ( $wp_filter as $filter_name => $filter_properties ):
        foreach ( $filter_properties->callbacks as $priority ):
            foreach( $priority as $function ):
                if( is_object( $function["function"] ) == true ):
                    unset( $wp_filter[ $filter_name ] );
                endif;
            endforeach;
        endforeach;
endforeach;
```